# Columns are being continuously repeated when after running a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a macro to copy specific cells from one sheet and paste them onto another. Upon running the macro it is copying and pasting, but it is also copying and pasting into every single column in row 2 on the other sheet I am pasting to. I've used the same code on other projects before and it does not behave like that and I am not sure what to google to resolve my issue. Hoping someone can help me see what I am missing.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub Submit_Work_Order()

    Range("F4:M4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

And it is resulting in

[image: Repeating columns starting at column I]

Comment: Worth a read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: `Rows("2:2").Select` selects the entire row, then you insert on the entire row.

Comment: You should better explain what the desired result should be. If you could post a screenshot of the initial worksheet and another one showing the desired results, you would surely get an answer.